# custom field with links

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I want to create a custom field, let's say Tickets in which I can store different links for each post.
For example:

On a post page I have a button called  "Buy ticket" which has a specific link, also on another post I have the same "Buy ticket" but with another link and so on ... 
How can I make this ? 
Thanks

Comment: From 0 to 100 in nano-moments, congrats and thx!

Comment: lol, now somebody could help me with this ?

Comment: As a matter of fact, this is a very basic issue. [Research](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bcustom+%2Bfields) this Stack and take a look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). I'm sure you'll be able to sort it out.

Comment: @Alecs The downvotes you received are for the lack of any research effort (code) whatsoever. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go with an example...

**Custom Field Name:** `buy-ticket`
**Custom Field Value:** `http://example.com/link-to-ticket/`

And you said, you want a button called "Buy ticket" linking to the Custom Field Value. This how you do it:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'buy-ticket', true); ?>" title="Buy a ticket right away!">
    <span>Button text or code here</span>
</a>
```

**SOURCE:** [WordPress Codex Function Reference/get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

**PS:** You can disregard the `<span>` tag. I used it for cosmetic purposes. :)